# Photo deleted but reappears when taking a new photo

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, android-camerax

The app I am making need to take pictures to send them to a server.

I need to take 6 photos at least. I have a recyclerView in which I am displaying a preview of my photo. It's working perfectly (I am using Picasso as photo library).

I need to be able to delete photos before sending them away (and consequently their preview). With a click on the preview, I remove it from my photo tab and update my recyclerview with notifyDataSetChanged().
The photo disappears.

When I take an other picture, I have its preview but the preview from the deleted picture is coming back.
If I delete three pictures and take a new one, I have the preview of the new one and the preview of the 3 deleted pictures.

Here's part of my adapter where I bind my view

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        mImageView = holder.mPhotoIV;
        File mFile = new File(String.valueOf(Uri.parse(mListOfPhotos.get(position))));

        int width = mImageView.getLayoutParams().width;
        int height = mImageView.getLayoutParams().height;

        Picasso.get()
                .load(mFile)
                .resize(200, 200)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_no_photo_foreground)
                .into(mImageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

Here part of my activity where I'm calling my adapter

```
        mTakePhotoFAB.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            mDir = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "PhotosAuthentifier");
            boolean success = true;

            if (!mDir.exists()) {
                success = mDir.mkdir();
            }

            if (success) {
                File mFile = new File(mDir, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + ".jpg");

                mImageCapture.takePicture(mFile,
                        new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                                mListOfPhotos.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                                mNumberOfPhotoTV.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.minPhotos, mListOfPhotos.size()));

                                if (mListOfPhotos.size() >= 6) {
                                    mSendPhotoFAB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }

                                mAdapter = new CameraPhotoAdapter(mListOfPhotos, getBaseContext());
                                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                            }


                            @Override
                            public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError imageCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                                String mMessage = "Photo capture failed: " + message;
                                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, mMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                assert cause != null;
                                cause.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
            }

        });
```

Function (in my adapter) to remove picture

```
        protected void removePhoto(Context context, ArrayList<String> array, int position) {

            File mDir = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), "PhotosAuthentifier");
            File mFile = new File(array.get(position));

            if (mDir.exists()) {
                File[] mFilesIntoDir = mDir.listFiles();

                if (mFilesIntoDir == null) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mFilesIntoDir.length; i++) {
                        if (mFilesIntoDir[i].getAbsolutePath().equals(mFile.getAbsolutePath())) {
                            boolean mSuccess = mFilesIntoDir[i].delete();

                            if (mSuccess) {
                                Picasso.get().invalidate(mFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                mListOfPhotos.remove(mFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried to invalidate Picasso cache but when I take a new picture, instead of the deleted picture reappearing I have the default behavior when I don't have a good url to upload (a black cross)

Could anyone help please :)?

Comment: Where do you get mListOfPhotos from? It is possible that you're only removing the photo in your local (adapter) instance of the list, while it stays on the main list (used by the code bit that re-creates your adapter).

​

I'd also recommend against re-creating the adapter every time - the whole point of the adapter is that you create a single instance, and then update its data source (mListOfPhotos) from the outside. Re-creating it is a costly procedure compared to updating its data source.

Comment: Did it help you @Lena ?

Comment: It worked! I created a method into my Adapter called "setmListOfPhotos". In my Activity, I create my Adapter in my method onCreate and when I need to pass data to it, I only call the method setmListOfPhotos. 
Is it a good way to do it?

Comment: It is. Also do not forget that the adapter should only be responsible for holding the list you're displaying, not mutating it! External updates like with the method you created are okay, but anything you do within the adapter with the list should never propagate out. @Lena

Comment: @Pie Thank you very much for your help and your explanations!

Comment: You can email me for android assistance whatisimp4u@gmail.com @Lena